# How to compare Strings in if-else statements?

Tags: java, jsp, if-statement

I wonder if anyone could give me a pointer with some pre-population in JSP:

So I am attempting to pre-populate a checkbox depending on the value in the customers database record. The checkbox would be checked if there is a 1 in the field, the other option would be a 0 - where the checkbox should be empty.

I am currently using this code within the input:

```
<%if (UPDATEDPREFERENCES != null)
{ 
    if (ISNEWSLETTER != "0") {
        out.println("checked");
    } 
}
%>
```

so it would be:

```
<input type='checkbox' class="newsletter" name='temp_ISNEWSLETTER_FIELD' id="temp_ISNEWSLETTER_FIELD" <%if (UPDATEDPREFERENCES != null)
{ 
    if (ISNEWSLETTER != "0") {
        out.println("checked");
    } 
}
%>/>
```

As it stands, it pre-populates fine. However, it also populates if the field is 0. If I change it to read:

```
if (ISNEWSLETTER == "1")
```

then the checkbox is empty whether it's a 1 or 0.

Am I missing something obvious? I am not a developer, I am in NYC and my support is in Belgium - they've all left for the day.

Comment: Here we go again... Is this homework week or so? I answered smiliar questions in `[jsp]` almost daily this week :/

Comment: Thanks BalusC - as I said, I'm not a developer. Your help is appreciated though. thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: I was so free to improve the title so that it's better searchable (I couldn't immediately find any duplicate questions while I'm sure that they exist) and better referenceable for future duplicates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Strings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) are [objects](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), not [primitives](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). Use [`equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), not `==`/`!=`. The `==`/`!=` won't check if they contain the same value, but if they point to the same object reference. The `equals()` will check if they contain the same value.

So, instead of `if (ISNEWSLETTER != "0")` you should use

```
if (!ISNEWSLETTER.equals("0"))
```

and instead of `if (ISNEWSLETTER == "1")` you should use

```
if (ISNEWSLETTER.equals("1"))
```

This problem is not related to JSP. You would have exactly the same problem when doing so in a normal Java class (where this kind of code *actually* belongs).

As an alternative, since they represent numbers, you could also just convert `ISNEWSLETTER` to an `int`. It's a primitive, so you should be able to use `==`/`!=` the usual way. You can if necessary convert a `String` to an `int` using [`Integer#parseInt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29). Or, even more, if it actually represents a boolean state (it can only be `true` or `false`), then you should rather use `boolean` instead. You can just use it straight in the `if` condition without any need for comparisons.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, your method if (ISNEWSLETTER.equals("1")) worked perfectly. thank you for you assistance!